# How to combine multiple rows into one row in hql?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the case, lets say 3 tables, class, student, and grade.

Relation:  class 1:many students,  students many: 1 grade.

Meaning: one student can only attend one class, one class might have multiple students. And One student can only have one grade.

Entities:  I just simplify them

```
Class class{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private Set<Students> students;
   //getter setter
}

Class student{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private Class  class;
   private Grade grades
   //getter setter
}

Class Grade{
   private int id;
   private char grade;
   private Set<Student> students;
   //getter setter
}
```

I also have a result class:

```
 Class Result{
     private String name;
     private String status;
     private String grade;
     private long count;
     public Result(name,status){ //omit}
     public Result(name,grade,count){ //omit}
     //getter setter
 }
```

Now to find number of grades each class has:

```
class    grade   count
math      A      2
math      B      10
science   A      2
ans so on
```

the hql I am using:

```
@Query("select new Result(class.name, grade.grade, count(*) as numOfCount) from Class class
left join class.students as student
left join student.grade as grade
group by class.name, grade.grade order by class.name");
public List<Result> findResult(Pagable pagable);
```

This hql will product list of result object like above with pagination, and I can loop through to get each result. Now for display reason, I want to have something like this:

```
class       status
math      A,2 | B, 1
science      A, 2
```

What should I add to the above hql to have a such result? I have to product something like that in hql, I can't do it in Java. Reason is because of pagination.

Let me explain: if now the page size is 2, and we just use the above hql, we will get:

```
 class    grade   count
    math      A      2
    math      B      10
```

and in Java we make it into math A,2 | B, 1, this will only show one row, but we need 2.

---

If hql is not possible, how can I do it in native query. I checked on sql, it has listagg.

```
 @Query(value="select name, listagg(status,'|') within group(order by status) 
       from (select cl.name, gr.grade|| ',' ||count(*) as status from CLASS cl, 
               Grade gr, Student, st
               where cl.classId = st.classId and gr.studentId= st.studentId 
               group by cl.name,  gr.grade order by cl.name
       ) group by name", nativeQuery=true)
  public list<Result> findResult();
```

This native oracle sql will give desired result, I test it in oracle sql developer. But in spring, I have trouble convert it into Result object. It gives can't not convert to Result exception.

Please help. Either help native query or hql will do the job. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change return-type to List in last `findResult()` (I think it will be `List<Object[]>` or something like that) and than transform result in `List<Result>` by for-loop.

Or you can use [SqlResultSetMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) for your native query mapping.